# Unable to upgrade MvvmCross to 6.2.0

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, mvvmcross, nuget-package

I have an old cross platform mobile app project which has been developed (and maintained) using Xamarin on Visual Studio 2017. The iOS app has now run into problems following iOS 11 (mainly camera issues - I have already added the new Entitlement - NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription - to Info.plist, so this is not the issue). Now, When I ask NuGet, on the portable project, to upgrade the MvvmCross dependency from 5.7.0 to 6.2.0, I get this error:

> Could not install package 'MvvmCross 6.2.0'. You are trying to 
>   install this package into a project that targets 
>   .NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not
>   contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

### Update

Figured out where to change .NET Framework to 4.6, but whenever I try, it reverts automatically to 4.5 when I click OK.

[image]

Comment: Convert your PCL Profile 111 project to a .NetStandard 2.0 based one

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks. I realized that late last night :) - which promptly brought me a whole new batch of joy - like old dependencies like the mvvmcross sqlite library being gone. Ah well, I guess that's just how it goes with old code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who really isn't a .NET nor app developer, I just want to leave the
solution to the problem here.

After much reading of articles, I found, that the solution was, as SushiHangover also pointed out, to migrate the Core project from PCL to Standard.

This article goes some way to describing what, when, where, and how-ish: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/standard/net-standard#comparison-to-portable-class-libraries

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As the error message is telling you, your project targets .NET 4.5, which MVVMCross 6.2.0 does not support.  [fuget.org](https://www.fuget.org/packages/MvvmCross/6.2.0/lib/netstandard2.0/MvvmCross.dll/MvvmCross) lists the targets that are supported.  You will need to update your project to use one of the supported targetsl

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm not well versed in .NET development, and I can't seem to find the place where I can change the .NET version of the portable project. I tried properties->targets, but 4.6.2 (which is installed on the system) doesn't show up as an option.

Comment: @MartinJesRasmussen You need to convert the project to a NetStd2.0 based one.